# How to display html file content through socket in c++ (linux)?

Tags: c++, sockets

I am implementing a server in c++. Whenever a request from client is coming I am parsing that request and checking if the request is for GET/HEAD. If the request is for GET I have to display the content of file.
My problem is that if it is a text file content is properly coming on the browser, but if it is html file request then browser is showing html file source code. 
I need some hint or some direction , how can I display content of html file?

Code Snippet:

```
if(c.r_type == "GET")
{
  ifstream file;
  char *readblock;
  size_t size;
  file.open(c.r_filename.c_str());
  if (send(c.r_acceptid,c.r_ctype.c_str(), strlen(c.r_ctype.c_str()), 0) == -1)
    perror("send");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    file.seekg (0, ios::end);
    size = file.tellg();
    readblock = new char [size];
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    file.read(readblock, size);
  }
      else
        cout<<"Never went Inside"<<endl;
  if (send(c.r_acceptid, readblock, size, 0) == -1)
       perror("send");
  file.close();
  delete [] readblock;
  close(c.r_acceptid);
}
```

Comment: The natural thing to suspect would be that you don't the the content-type field in the HTTP response header set correctly to text/html. But you're not showing where you generate the response header at all.

Comment: that's the problem I dnt knw the flow, do I need to send the response header before sending the content

Comment: Step away from the keyboard now and read a basic introduction to HTTP before you try to implement the protocol! The RFC itself (RFC-2616) might do in a pinch, but you'll probably want something more pedagogical to start with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. :big-grin: not sure which comment was funnier - yours or the one you were responding to..